# Storing custom QGIS form in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I would like to store my custom `.ui` form in the QGIS style saved in PostgreSQL, so I can load it within the layer.

The option is here when you save the style, but I can't see it stored on the database and can' load it.

Has someone already did it? It would help me a lot because I can't install it on each computer.

Maybe a hack by modifying the XML definition in the table?

Comment: All your styles are saved in a table named public.layer_styles, you can copy it (create a file with the extension *.BACUP), respectively, and transferred to any PC to a different database...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i'm looking to do is save the custom form (.ui) in the layer_styles table. There is an option for tthat when you save the style in database but I seems that there is a bug.

Comment: To save a custom form (.ui), another solution is required ...